# Eloquent Conditional Update

Tags: php, database, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent in Laravel 3 and would like to know what the best practices are for conditionally updating a record in a database table.  I have the key in my model set to the 'email' field and have found that I can do a check using the find() method and if nothing is found I can create a new instance of the model and save the record but this approach looks/feels clunky and cumbersome.

What is the cleanest way to see if a record exists matching a key value that is passed in and based on that create a new record or just update an existing one?

```
    $form = FormDB::find('blah@blah.com');

    if($form) {
        $form->text = "Updated";
        $form->save();
    } else {
        $form = new FormDB;
        $form->email = "blah@blah.com";
        $form->text = "Inserted";
        $form->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$form = !FormDB::find('blah@blah.com') ? new FormDB : FormDB::find('blah@blah.com');
$form->email = !$form->email ? "blah@blah.com" : $form->email;
$form->text = !$form->text ? "Inserted" : "Updated";
$form->save();
```

Comment: That does tighten things up a bit and after doing some more investigating and looking at other code I realized my solution really wasn't all that bulky.  Thanks Sheikh!